Why did the first movie’s Voldemort have a nose?
According to this answer,

a series of experiments with Dark Magic periodically deformed his appearance.

During the period of the first book/movie, Voldemort wasn’t the innocent young Tom Riddle without any experience in dark magic. Then, how come he had a nose?


Terrible!! No, wait. I've got that one wrong...

I was expecting the answer to be "because the films came out while the books were still ongoing and the filmmakers didn't know what Voldemort would look like in the books", but the Philosopher's Stone film released a full year after Goblet of Fire established Voldemort's snakelike nose. So there's an interesting question here.

@F1Krazy Assuming it was done with prosthetics, it's the filming date, not the release date, that matters; but your point probably stands, because according to Wikipedia, principal filming began in September 2000, and Goblet of Fire had been released in July. And since Rowling was involved in the film's production, she would have been able to tell them the description even before then.

it is worse the Philosopher´s stone book clearly describes Voldemort with slits like a snake so the description of Voldemort with no nose predates his resurrection and he have no nose in his first apparition.
